# How to turn off "change" address in bitcoind?

Tags: bitcoin-core, change

I would like to keep backup of my wallet on paper, but that's impossible or at least impractical when the bitcoind keeps creating new addresses for "change". I know it is possible in theory to do it by sending the change back to the sending address. And I know there are privacy implications when doing this. But I care more about security than anonymity in my case.

Is there an option to turn off "change" addresses in bitcoind (the original Satoshi client)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitcoind isn't designed for that. There isn't option for that and probably won't be. If you are interested in keeping paper backup, you should look at clients such as [Electrum](https://electrum.org/).

Comment: I guess "electrum or electrum" isn't what you meant to write : P